# Error while rounding TimeStamp: unexpected keyword argument 'freq'

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a problem with rounding TimeStamp to seconds resolution.
My siple code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';',parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'])
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], unit='s') 
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(df['TIMESTAMP'])
```

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].round(freq = 'S')
```

produces this error:

```
TypeError: round() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
```

Example data:

```
   2019-04-05 10:43:22.666666752
   2019-04-05 10:43:23.000000000
   2019-04-05 10:43:23.333333248
Name: TIMESTAMP, dtype: datetime64[ns]>
```

Comment: Not sure why but  
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pandas.Series(df['TIMESTAMP']).dt.round("S") worked.

Comment: can you paste the first few values?

Comment: You are using pandas round attribute which according to documentation

> Round a DataFrame to a variable number of decimal places.

So, it will not accept keyword argument 'freq'.
Solution provided by @I.P. should work.

Comment: @r_hudson What about this documentation [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html)?

Comment: @I.P., OP is performing datetime index operation on column, I think they will have to first set that column to index and do rounding.